# Using Ruby, how can I take a string and insert pipes between the words?

Tags: ruby, string

Let's say I have this string:

"birthday cake is my favorite"

I need to convert that to:

"birthday|cake|is|my|favorite"

How would I go about doing that with Ruby?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Always nice to be able to answer not using a regex :-)

```
your_string.split(" ").join("|")
```

should do it.

Comment: Use split(/[^\w]+/).join("|") if you want all non-word characters stripped out.
"birthday cake: my favorite".split(/[^\w]+/).join("|") #=> "birthday|cake|my|favorite"

EDIT: Ha, just saw your comment about not using a regex. Makes my comment a little ironic.

Answer (score 7):

```
"birthday cake is my favorite".gsub(" ", "|")
```

Comment: you might want `.gsub(/ +/,"|")` to combine multiple spaces into one pipe char.

Comment: I'd use \s+ - using a literal blank for whitespace in a regex bothers me for some reason.

Answer (score 5):

This is *precisely* what `String#tr` (and `String#tr_s`) is for:

```
# Look, Ma! No Regexp!
'birthday cake is my     favorite'.tr_s(' ', '|')
# => "birthday|cake|is|my|favorite"
```

I admit, the method names aren't the most intuitive. (Unless you are a Mac OSX, Unix, Linux, Cygwin or MinGW user, of course, in which case `tr` and `tr -s` will be part of your daily arsenal.)